# How to use Instance as Attributes?

Tags: python, class

Let me show a quick example:

If I want to use `Tank` Class instance as the car's attribute. At the same time, I want the method `tank_info`, to give different tank size, according to different model in the `Car` class.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank()

    def get_car_info(self):
        long_name = self.make + ' ' + self.model
        print('The car is', long_name)

class Tank():
    def __init__(self, tank_size=20):
        self.tank_size = tank_size
    def tank_info(self):
        print('The tank size is', self.tank_size, 'gallons')

my_car = Car('Audi', 'A4')
my_car.get_car_info()
my_car.tank.tank_info()
```

Let's say, Audi has A4, A6, and A8, their tank size are 20, 25, 30.
How should I write the `tank_info` method, for it to automatically tell what tank size it has?

Comment: Do you want to hardcode the tank size for the different models or do you want to pass in the size as additional argument for `Car.__init__`?

Comment: Use a dictionary to map cars to tank sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the input of tank size by encapsulating the tank size mapping in a separate dictionary.

The following example shows how you can build the logic dynamically. The car tank size is encapsulated in a dictionary of tank size dictionary where the outer key represents the model and the inner key represents the make. If you want to add more car models or makes, you just need to add them to the car_tank_sizes dictionary.

Also note that if tank sizes are not specified, it defaults to 20.

```
class Car():
    car_tank_sizes = {'Audi': {'A4': '20', 'A6': 25, 'A8': 30}}

    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank(Car.car_tank_sizes.get(self.make,{}).get(self.model))

    def get_car_info(self):
        long_name = self.make + ' ' + self.model
        print('The car is', long_name)


class Tank():
    def __init__(self, tank_size):
        if (tank_size is None):
            self.tank_size = 20
        else:
            self.tank_size = tank_size

    def tank_info(self):
        print('The tank size is', self.tank_size, 'gallons')


my_car = Car('Audi', 'A6')
my_car.get_car_info()
my_car.tank.tank_info()
```

The following alternate approach shows how to encapsulate tank size inside Tank itself.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank(self.make, self.model)

    def get_car_info(self):
        long_name = self.make + ' ' + self.model
        print('The car is', long_name)


class Tank():
    car_tank_sizes = {'Audi': {'A4': '20', 'A6': 25, 'A8': 30}}

    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.tank_size = Tank.car_tank_sizes.get(make, {}).get(model, 20)

    def tank_info(self):
        print('The tank size is', self.tank_size, 'gallons')


my_car = Car('Audi', 'A4')
my_car.get_car_info()
my_car.tank.tank_info()
```

Comment: SO eventually, this dictionary has to be in the Car class, instead of in the Tank class. Would it possible to write in a way in the Tank class, because that seems to be more organized.

Comment: You can just move the dictionary to Tank and then in Car call it as Tank. car_tank_sizes. Or alternatively the whole logic can be in the Tank's init method.

Comment: because the idea to is make everything related to Tank information independent from Car class. Otherwise, I can just easily setup this inside the Car class without having to have a Tank class

Comment: In that case, Tank would need to know make and model of car. You can pass make and model to Tank's init method. I have update the above answer with the alternate approach.

Comment: Thanks! You are so great!!! This question has been haunting me since last night, can't sleep without knowing how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You can accept a `tank_size` argument into `Car`

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, tank_size):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank(tank_size)
```

So now your example

```
my_car = Car('Audi', 'A4', 20)
my_car.get_car_info()
my_car.tank.tank_info()
```

will output

```
The car is Audi A4
The tank size is 20 gallons
```

Comment: But what I want here, is to avoid input tank_size myself. Insteand, I want the tanks_info method to automatically give different tank size just based on the car model. Simply speaking, to link the self.model to tank_size, and create a relationship, or a dictionary out of it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the tank size in the instance. So when you are creating the Tank object you assign the size as well. This is where you are creating the tank of the car and thus create the new size.

```
        self.tank = Tank(tank_size)
```

earlier it was

```
        self.tank = Tank()
```

And this would call

```
class Tank():
    def __init__(self, tank_size=20):
        self.tank_size = tank_size
```

Since you were not passing in the `tank_size`, all cars were assigned 20 size by default, which happens due to  `tank_size=20`.

---

```
sizes={
        'Audi': {
                 'A4':25,
                 'A6':30,
                 'A8':35
                },
        'BMW':  {
                 'Series 3':1,
                 'Series 6':2
                }
}

class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, tank_size):
        global sizes
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank(sizes[make][model])

    def get_car_info(self):
        long_name = self.make + ' ' + self.model
        print('The car is', long_name)


class Tank():
    def __init__(self, tank_size=20):
        self.tank_size = tank_size
    def tank_info(self):
        print('The tank size is', self.tank_size, 'gallons')

my_car = Car('Audi', 'A4',33)
my_car.get_car_info()
my_car.tank.tank_info()
```

Comment: But what I want here, is to avoid input tank_size myself. Insteand, I want the tanks_info method to automatically give different tank size just based on the car model. Simply speaking, to link the self.model to tank_size, and create a relationship, or a dictionary out of it?

Comment: fixed to have a dictionary